# How can i get specific user data from firestore in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So the problem is, when i'm trying to get the details by using forEach function it gives me all the user's details which is available on the firestore..let me explain with code:

Here is my code for getting details in Profile Page :

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

class ProfilePage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        profiledata : null
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        firestore.collection('profiledata')
            // .doc("JgT2LyOB4jqhMv9YMgrh")
            .get()
            
             .then((snapshot) => {
                const profiledata  = []
                snapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                    const data = doc.data();
                    profiledata.push(data);
                }
                )
                this.setState({profiledata :  profiledata})
                })
                }
             
            render(){
        return(
            <div className='profile'>
                <h1>User</h1>
                {
                    this.state.profiledata && 
                        this.state.profiledata.map( profiledata => {
                            return(
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        First Name : {String(profiledata.firstname)}
                                        Last Name : {String(profiledata.lastname)}
                                        Company Name : {String(profiledata.companyname)}
                                                                        
                                        </p>
                                </div>
                                
                            )
                        })
                }
                </div>
        )
    }export default ProfilePage;
```

Comment: You're reading the entire `profiledata` collection, so it makes sense you get the profile data for all users. What happens if you uncomment the ` // .doc("JgT2LyOB4jqhMv9YMgrh")`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Frank in the comments you are querying the entire collection `profileData` without a referencing a specific document or filtering it, so the expect result is to get all users, which is exactly what you are getting.

In order to get a specific document, as you can see in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) you have to reference a documentId in your call with `.doc()`, like you apparently were doing in the commented out part of your, so if you do this:

```
firestore.collection('profiledata')
         .doc("JgT2LyOB4jqhMv9YMgrh")
         .get()
```

You should get the user with id `JgT2LyOB4jqhMv9YMgrh`, if it exists.